# Gremlin, join multiples VERTEX base on an Id and add a EDGE in Titan graph db

Tags: join, graph, gremlin, titan, edges

Having these VERTEX maps

```
 **a**) ( County, StreetName, GroupName, Type, BaseRecId, Latitude,
          StreetSuffix, Longitude, StreetNumber, Zip, City )
 **b**) ( SalesPrice, SalesRecId, BaseRecId, SalesDate )
```

I need to create EDGES ( 1 to many ), from VERTEX **a** to VERTEX **b** when the **PROPERTY** **BaseRecId** MATCHES.

Comment: rexster[groovy]> properties = g.V('GroupName', 'PROPERTY').next()
==>v[14860]
rexster[groovy]> sales = g.V('GroupName', null).next()
==>v[24012]
rexster[groovy]> g.addEdge(properties,sales,'SOLD')
==>e[uIv-3RG-58][14860-SOLD->24012]
rexster[groovy]> g.commit()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First select all vertices of Group a, then the matching vertices of Group b and finally link them together:

```
g.V().hasNot("BaseRecId", null).hasNot("GroupName", null).as("a").transform({
  g.V("BaseRecId", it.getProperty("BaseRecId")).hasNot("SalesRecId", null)
}).scatter().linkIn("label", "a")
```

**Assumptions in this query:**

- each vertex in Group a has a GroupName
- each vertex in Group b has a SalesRecId
- BaseRecId is indexed (this is optional, but would speed things dramatically up)

This should work for a small graph. For larger graphs use Faunus.